# How to handle changing mysql host in php files

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, load-balancing

I have a server `1.1.1.1` which acts as a load balancer and also runs mysql. I also have a cluster server `1.1.1.2` which when accessing mysql with php runs the command:

```
mysqli_connect("1.1.1.1","username","password","db");
```

---

I now have a backup server `3.3.3.3` which has mysql installed and all the php files are being rsynced from 1.1.1.2 to it.

But the issue is now all my mysqli connections should look like:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");
```

but they don't. What is the best way to deal with this situation dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean "but they don't"?

Comment: As the `.php` files  are being rsynced, they stay the same (stating the obvious) but I need them to change.

Comment: you should redesign your application the way when only ONE php file has `mysqli_connect` command

Comment: But that method is likely to annoy other users on my server.

Comment: I am wondering if I can modify a php file so that php thinks that `1.1.1.1` is `localhost`

Comment: `$localhost = '1.1.1.1'; mysqli_connect($localhost ...`

Comment: sorry a php configuation file